# How to add permission for "web users"?

Tags: php, ubuntu, dbus

I need to set access rights for PHP to the file ~/.dbus

I know that I need to use something like

```
 chown -R <your user>:<your group> ~/.dbus
```

But which user and group? 
www-data?

Comment: It depends on what user you are running PHP as. `www-data` might make sense if you were running it from a web server, but I can't see any reason why a web server would need access to `.dbus` in your home directory.

Comment: @Quentin I need it to run normal firefox for selenium.

Comment: Normally you'd run selenium as … yourself. So you shouldn't need to chown anything.

Comment: @Quentin nope. I run python selenium in pp.py by php. `shell_exec("python3 pp.py")` But selenium send me error 

**Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:**